# Entity Framework Code first doesn't insert anything in junction table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I am trying to create a web app using ASP.net MVC.
The app draws complete graphs in the browser, using the javascript library `cytoscape`. 
 The javascript object is generated using the info inserted in a table at the front-end, then this object is passed to the cytoscape and the graph is created. These all works fine and is the front-end work. No need to worry about it. **But** the web app should be able to *store* the graph in the database. this is why I have to have a back-end side and it has to be ASP.NET MVC.
To store the graph, I convert the javascript object that was used to create the graph, to `JSON` and I pass it to my back-end using `AJAX`. 
Now in the back-end side, the CONTROLLER's "Store" method, gets the `JSON` string, then it deserilizes it, passes it to EF and I would expect the whole thing will be stored in the database and it does, except for the **JUNCTION TABLE**, which is created but has NO values.

---

Now here is my Model. Say this JSON comes to the controller:

```
{
"nodes":
    [
        {"data":{"id":"r1"}},
        {"data":{"id":"r2"}},
        {"data":{"id":"r3"}}
    ],
"edges":
    [
        {"data":{"id":"r1r2","source":"r1","target":"r2"}},
        {"data":{"id":"r1r3","source":"r1","target":"r3"}},
        {"data":{"id":"r2r3","source":"r2","target":"r3"}}
    ]
}
```

And here is the models

```
public class Edge
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public EdgeData data { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
public class EdgeData
{
    [Key]
    public int primaryKey { set; get; }
    public string id { set; get; }
    public string source { set; get; }
    public string target { set; get; }
}
public class Node
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public NodeData data { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Edge> Edges { get; set; }
}
public class NodeData
{
    [Key]
    public int primaryKey { set; get; }
    public string id { set; get; }
}
public class Elements
{
    public int id { set; get; } 
    public List<Node> nodes { set; get; }
    public List<Edge> edges { set; get; }
}
```

And here is the DbContext Class:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Elements> elements { set; get; }
}
```

And finally here is the Controller method :

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Store(string jsonObj)
{
    var elements = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Elements>(jsonObj);
    using (var db = new Context())
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        db.elements.Add(elements);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return true;
}
```

The Problem is that despite everything is saved alright, but the `junction table` for many to many relation is **EMPTY** in the SQLServer2017.

Any help please?

Comment: What is `public List nodes { set; get; }` - `List<what>`? And the parameter in you POST method should be a model representing that data, not a `string`

Comment: And what 'junction table' are you referring to?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Believe me It IS "public List<Node> nodes { set; get; }" (I tried to edit the question and saw that it's correct in fact) but it shows as "List nodes". And for the post method is it really matter in this case? The problem is that the many-to-many relationship is not made and the table is created empty. And the "Junction table" I mean the third table for the many-to-many relations in the database where it has the primary keys of two other tables?

Comment: How would EF know which nodes and edges are related? You only offer two independent collections.

Comment: @GertArnold I thought that will be handled automatically with EF. So how should I tell EF which nodes and edges are related?

Comment: Yes, in your code each `Node` has an empty collection of edges.

Comment: @GertArnold You are right I debugged and the lists are empty. But I don't understand. I am new to dot net, but as far as I know, for the n to n relationships all I have to do is to define a virtual list of each entity in the other one and set 'lazy' to true. All the rest is supposed to be automatically done. No? So what to do here?

Comment: I think the main problem is your store (entity) model. The `Edge` (or `EdgeData`) is basically a junction table. The way I see it you have many-to-many self relationship `Node` <-> `Node` through `Edge`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I followed your advice and changed the entire model. For that, I had to change the JSON that is passed to the controller. For example the following : "nodes": [ {"data":{"id":"r1"}}, {"data":{"id":"r2"}} ] is now converted to this: "nodes": [ {"id":"r1"}, {"id":"r2"} ] . Same with the "edges". Now I can remove the NodeData and EdgeData classes. My model is now looking like this: Node.cs, Edge.cs, Elements.cs Much more simpler and better thanks for that, But the same exact problem remains. The Junction table is empty. It's created but empty.

Comment: You probably have to separate the JSON model from EF model. The way I see it, you deserialize JSON to some classes which represent JSON structure, then map them to EF objects and apply to the database. The class `Edge` in EF should be something like `public class Edge { public int Id { get; set; } public string Key { get; set; } public int SourceId { get; set; } public Node Source { get; set; } public int TargetId { get; set; } public Node Target { get; set; } }`. You can start from here. hope you see the point.

Comment: @IvanStoev It Worked. I did what you said. I created two packages in my Models. JModels and DModels. JModels, contains the classes to be automatically created with the JSON, and DModels contain the classes to be created FROM the JModel classes. Then I store the DModels in the db and everything works fine. Sorry for bad English I'm trying to describe the solution as clear as I can. In one sentence, "I separated the JSON part from the EF part." If you post the comment as an answer I can choose it as correct solution and this thread is closed. Thank you very much for the Help.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :) But all I did was to share some thoughts/hints. The solution is all yours! So you can post a self answer with the solution and I'll be happy to vote it up. Or just move on :) Cheers.